# Finding the distribution of $Z$, which is the product of two independent Pareto distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider two independent random variables, $X$ and $Y$. Both follow a [Pareto distribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParetoDistribution.html) with minimum value $1$ and shape parameters $\alpha_X$ and $\alpha_Y$, respectively. Hence, the PDFs are given by

\begin{align*}
f_X(x) &= \alpha_X ~ x^{-\alpha_X-1} \\
f_Y(y) &= \alpha_Y ~ y^{-\alpha_Y-1}.
\end{align*}

I need to find the distribution of $Z$, which is the product of $X$ and $Y$: $Z \equiv XY$.

---

**What I've tried:** The distribution of $Z$ seems to be a [product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) and according to the linked page the PDF of $Z$ should be

\begin{align*}
f_{Z}(z)=\int _{{-\infty }}^{{\infty }}f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(z/x\right){\frac  {1}{|x|}}\,dx.
\end{align*}

However, trying to use this formula turned out to be problematic due to the following reasons (or due to my inexperience):

First, integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ seems problematic if my distribution has a minimum value of $1$. I therefore replaced the lower bound of the integral by $1$ (should I?). Besides, if the lower bound is $1$, then using the absolute value of $x$ seems superfluous. Therefore, after plugging in my PDFs from above and integrating, I get:

\begin{align*}
f_Z(z) = \alpha_X \alpha_Y z^{-\alpha_Y-1} \left[ \frac{1}{-\alpha_X+\alpha_Y} x^{-\alpha_X+\alpha_Y} \right]_1^\infty.
\end{align*}

This raises the second issue: I expected the terms where I plug in $\infty$ to vanish. This however only happens if $\alpha_X > \alpha_Y$ (negative exponent of $x$). I do not see any plausible reason why such a constraint should be necessary (after all, $Z= XY$; both random variables enter $Z$ "the same way", therefore I expect a "symmetric" result). Anyway, going with this assumption I get:

\begin{align*}
f_Z(z) = \frac{\alpha_X \alpha_Y}{\alpha_X - \alpha_Y} z^{-\alpha_Y-1}
\end{align*}

I suspect this to be wrong due to my aforementioned concerns about the limit of the integral and the assumption on the shape parameters. Moreover, there is [this very related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333767/product-of-two-independent-r-v-s-following-pareto-distributions) where a commentator points out that $\frac{z}{x}$ must be larger than the distribution's minimum value ($1$ in my case). This is clearly violated for sufficiently large $x$.

On the other hand, I think that the general approach is valid. The formula an the Wikipedia page is apparently correct (I even checked the [original source (p. 140)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118165676)). The formula suggested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55684/pdf-of-product-of-variables) leads me to the same result (after differentiating the resulting CDF – but subject to the same limitations as my initial approach).

Therefore, my question is:

> What is the distribution of $Z$ and what is wrong with my initial approach?

Comment: As you mentioned, the support of both $X, Y$ are $[1, +\infty)$. Therefore $f_X(x)f_Y(z/x) > 0$ if and only if $x > 1$ and $z/x > 1$, which gives you $1 < x < z$ and these will be your integral limits.

Comment: @BGM Thank you for this very helpful comment! This allowed me to derive \begin{align*}f_Z(z) &=  \left[ \frac{\alpha_X \alpha_Y}{\alpha_Y - \alpha_X} \right]  \left[ z^{-\alpha_X - 1} - z^{-\alpha_Y - 1} \right]\end{align*} (for $\alpha_X \neq \alpha_Y$) and \begin{align*}f_Z(z) &= \alpha^2 z^{-\alpha-1} \ln(z)\end{align*} (for $\alpha \equiv \alpha_X = \alpha_Y$). Would you mind fleshing out your comment to a full answer (potentially including my result)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested I write out a full derivation here.

Given the pdf of two independent random variables $X, Y$ are

$$ f_X(x) = \alpha_X x^{-\alpha_X-1}, ~~ x > 1$$
$$ f_Y(y) = \alpha_Y y^{-\alpha_Y-1}, ~~ y > 1$$

and equals to $0$ otherwise. The pdf of the product $Z = XY$ is given by

$$ f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y\left(\frac {z} {x}\right)\frac {1} {|x|}dx$$

Since the support of $X,Y$ are $(1, +\infty)$, the integrand $\displaystyle f_X(x)f_Y\left(\frac {z} {x}\right)\frac {1} {|x|}$ is non-zero if and only if

$$ f_X(x) > 0 \text{  and  } f_Y\left(\frac {z} {x}\right) > 0 
\iff x > 1 \text{  and  } \frac {z} {x} > 1 
\iff 1 < x < z$$

From this we also verified the obvious fact that the support of $Z$ is also $(1, +\infty)$ i.e. $f_Z(z) > 0 \iff z > 1$. So for the coming calculation, we are only interested in $z > 1$ only.

Now we can plug in the pdfs of $X, Y$, and only need to calculate when $x \in (1, z)$ as the integrand will vanish outside. The above integral becomes

$$ \begin{align} f_Z(z) 
&= \int_1^z \alpha_X x^{-\alpha_X-1} 
\alpha_Y \left(\frac {z} {x}\right)^{-\alpha_Y-1} \frac {1} {x} dx \\
&= \alpha_X\alpha_Y z^{-\alpha_Y-1} \int_1^z x^{-\alpha_X+\alpha_Y-1}dx \\
&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle 
\alpha_X\alpha_Y z^{-\alpha_Y-1} \left. \frac {x^{\alpha_Y-\alpha_X}} {\alpha_Y-\alpha_X}\right|_{x=1}^{x=z} 
& \text{when  } \alpha_X \neq \alpha_Y \\
\displaystyle 
\alpha_X\alpha_Y z^{-\alpha_Y-1} \left. \ln x \right|_{x=1}^{x=z} 
&\text{when  } \alpha_X =\alpha_Y \triangleq \alpha \\
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle 
\frac {\alpha_X\alpha_Y} {\alpha_Y - \alpha_X} z^{-\alpha_Y-1}(z^{\alpha_Y-\alpha_X}-1)  
& \text{when  } \alpha_X \neq \alpha_Y \\
\displaystyle 
\alpha^2 z^{-\alpha-1} \ln z
&\text{when  } \alpha_X =\alpha_Y \triangleq \alpha \\
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle 
\frac {\alpha_X\alpha_Y} {\alpha_Y - \alpha_X} (z^{-\alpha_X-1}-z^{-\alpha_Y-1})  
& \text{when  } \alpha_X \neq \alpha_Y \\
\displaystyle 
\alpha^2 z^{-\alpha-1} \ln z
&\text{when  } \alpha_X =\alpha_Y \triangleq \alpha \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

and $0$ otherwise. As a careful check, note that when $z > 1$, $\ln z > 0$ and 
$$ z^{-\alpha_X-1}-z^{-\alpha_Y-1} > 0 \iff \alpha_Y - \alpha_X > 0$$

So the calculated pdf is indeed positive for $z > 1$.

Comment: Thank you, BGM!